# JQuery filtering with quicksand

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, quicksand

I am using the example of quicksand

http://razorjack.net/quicksand/demos/one-set-clone.html

And it works just fine.

However he uses an outdated jquery version.

```
<script src="../scripts/assets/jquery-1.4.1-and-plugins.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried to add JQuery + Quicksand plugin but it completely stopped working.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/quicksand/1.2.2/jquery.quicksand.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am getting the following error message if I click on a filter.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeInOutQuad' jquery.min.js:2
cY.run jquery.min.js:2
i jquery.min.js:2
p.fx.timer jquery.min.js:2
cV jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.extend.animate.g jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.dequeue jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.extend.queue jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.extend.queue jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.extend.animate jquery.min.js:2
$.fn.quicksand jquery.quicksand.js:303
p.extend.each jquery.min.js:2
p.fn.p.each jquery.min.js:2
$.fn.quicksand jquery.quicksand.js:47
(anonymous function) one-set-clone.html:182
p.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
p.event.add.g.handle.h
```

I tried to remove `easing: 'easeInOutQuad'` but then nothing happens.

Any idea what went wrong?

Update1:

I figured I just missed a plugin

```
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.easing/1.3/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But now everything is hiding if I click a filter, did they change the API?

Comment: Try to use Jquery UI , see here seem to work: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/s8f8K/)

Comment: Okay it seems to work on jsfiddle, but I am not able to get it to work . It seems the only two dependecies are jquery 1.7.2 + jqueryui 1.8.18 right? My .html looks like this http://pastebin.com/mkbWhKHV

Comment: Yes and `jquery.quicksand.js`(see in manage resources) the code seem the same of your pastebin

Comment: OK, perfect, happy to be useful ;-)